# Datetimepicker between

Tags: c#, sql

```
string ssr;
SqlConnection scr = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC\MSSQL;Initial Catalog=Highscore;Integrated Security=True");
scr.Open();
ssr = "Select Nume,Scor,DataInitiala,DataRecenta FROM Users where DataInitiala between @Param and @Param1 ";
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(ssr, scr);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", dateTimePicker1.Value);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", dateTimePicker2.Value);
SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter1.SelectCommand = cmd2;
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
adapter1.Fill(ds1);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Any idea why it compares just dates and not time?It works fine for dates but it does not seem to mind the time. Please don't put this on hold just because you don't know the answer. Any part of the code that is relevant to my problem is here

The create table script:

```
CREATE
TABLE  Users
( ID int
, Nume varchar(20)
, Scor int
, DataInitiala datetime
, DataRecenta datetime
)



   private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

            }

            private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
            }
```

I added the tt for the format and it works now.Thx for the help

Comment: What is the value of your datepickers?

Comment: I added that because i asked this before and some smart guys put it on hold just because..this is the default value:6/13/2014 9:27 AM

Comment: If you asked it before, you should rather improve your question than repost. It will be most likely be closed again.

Comment: Can you give an example of the inputs and what values you expected them to match with in DataInitiala?

Comment: As far as I know, when you use `BETWEEN` with `datetime` values (If your `DataInitiala` column is `datetime`) and you didn't have time part, it is `12:00 AM` by default.

Comment: I had this problem when I accedently had date field instead of datetime is your database returning date and time?

Comment: Please provide the SQL type for your DateInitiala column

Comment: The Type is datetime 100% sure

Comment: Can you give us a create statement for your table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE Users
(
ID int,
Nume varchar(20),
Scor int,
DataInitiala datetime,
DataRecenta datetime
);

Comment: Regardless of anything else, [don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) especially in what is likely SQL Server.  Or for other continuous-range types (that is, anything other than an integer count).  Or at all, really.  You need to go back and improve your previous question, get it reopened, and accept an answer there.  For instance, supplying a small set of sample data with rows expected-but-not-returned would be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTimePicker C# Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181640/datetimepicker-c-sharp-select)